# PrimeFaces Growl is not working with google map on JSF Page

Tags: java, jsf, growl

p:growl works well on other pages that is not contain any Google Map, but when I use p:growl with Google Map on a jsf page then p:growl is not working. I inspect element of this page in chrome and it show this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'add' of undefined      primefaces.js.xhtml:16

Comment: Can you add full stacktrace and the relevant code?

Comment: What scripts are you importing for Google Map? One of them might have conflicted. Do you know that PrimeFaces has already a fully standalone component for Google Map, the [`<p:gmap>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/gmapBasic.jsf)? Why not just using that instead?

Comment: @Bhesh: that's not a Java exception. That's a JavaScript error. So there's no means of a stacktrace.

Comment: @BalusC: you are right this is javascript error. you have any solution for this? Thanks for reply

Comment: @BalusC: I need advance functionality of google map. p:map doesn't provide me that functionality, thats why i m using javascript API for google map v3.